# How to reset root password when denied access to user in ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have installed `phpmyadmin` on ubuntu ec2 instance. `Phpmyadmin` page is showing up in front page, but I am receiving error denying access to the root user. I had already set up password for the root during installation, but when I try to login using `mysql -u root -p` then I am getting error `access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: YES)`. How can I setup root password so that I can login into phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the password of the root user as follows:

1.- Stop the Mysql service

```
         service mysqld stop
```

O well:

```
        /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

2.- Start the MySQL service in open mode with the following command:

```
      mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

3.- Once MySQL is started, you must access it with the user “root”. For this you can do it simply with:

```
      mysql -u root
```

4.- Once inside MySQL, you will have to access the MySQL database, which is where you will have to change the password:

```
   mysql> use MySQL;
```

5.- Within the MySQL database, you can launch the following query that will make the password change:

```
    mysql> UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD ('password') WHERE user = 'root';
```

6.- And when it finishes you will be able to leave the MySQL server with:

```
    mysql> exit
```

7.- Finally you will have to restart the MySQL service so that it starts in normal mode:

```
    service mysqld restart
```

O well:

```
 /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

After completing the previous steps, you will have already modified the password of the MySQL “root” user.

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to use "mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &" it shows errors i.e. mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 144: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
2020-04-24T12:48:51.000160Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 144: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied

Comment: Yes, I did, but it not work. "mysqld" is not working.